# How to bind product image to email in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, product-images, email-templates

I have created custom module in which I need to bind product image to email template in Magento2.2.5?

My code:

```
$requestData["imgUrl"] = $data["shareProdImg"];


            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($requestData);

            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('custom_pdp_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom(['name' => $data["userName"],'email' => $data["userMail"]])
                ->addTo($data["shareMail"])
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
```

My template file:

```
<li style="font-weight:300;color:black !important;font-family: lato;font-size:16px;margin-left:0;">
                    {{depend data.imgUrl}}
                    {{trans "%imgUrl" imgUrl=$data.imgUrl}}<br/>
                    {{/depend}}
                </li>

                <li style="font-weight:300;color:black !important;font-family: lato;font-size:16px;margin-left:0;">
                     <img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: getImagepaypal() }" alt="Custom image" width="60" height="60">
                </li>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: actually you want to show your specific Product image in Email???

Comment: is  $postObject object or array?

Answer (score 0):

You have to punch to `$data["shareProdImg"]` add to **$postObject**.

> $postObject['imgUrl'] = $data["shareProdImg"];